# nginx configuration for expiration header

Tags: nginx

I need to do 2 things, first set the expiration header to 30d and second to enable the page speed module. Non of them work so far, this is my nginx.conf file

```conf
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]      "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; 
}
```

Comment: correct location is this `` location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css|xml)$ { expires           30d; }``

Answer (score 1):

For turning on pagespeed, you first need to build your nginx from source with pagespeed's module.
Its very easy! You could just follow Google's instruction [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source) and then [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration)

After you complied Nginx from source with pagespeed module enabled, you could just add this to your conf:

```
pagespeed on;
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
```

To set the expiration header, I think it's better to put your code inside a *server* block, and then inside the main *location* block. See [this](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2014/09/setting-expires-header-for-assets-nginx/) blog post but it uses an *if* clause if you don't mind.

If you are optimizing your website, maybe consider using **gzip on** too in your conf. It compress the content before sending them to your clients. It saves you a lot of bandwidth and I think it reduce the latency (faster load).

If you are decided to use gzip with pagespeed, make sure to add below line to your conf and [read](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/optimize-for-bandwidth)

`pagespeed FetchWithGzip on;`